# Testing with package manager

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-testing

I am attempting to write an Android test case that finds a receiver in the manifest. I'm using gradle. In my androidTest/res/AndroidManifest.xml, I have,

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.foo.MyReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
</receiver>
```

My test case looks like this,

```
try {
  ActivityInfo info = getSystemContext().getPackageManager().getReceiverInfo(
    new ComponentName("com.example.foo", "com.example.foo.MyReceiver"), 
    PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS);
  // do stuff
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
  // i'm thrown
}
```

The NameNotFoundException is thrown. Yes, my test's AndroidManifest.xml's package is "com.example.foo". My test class extends ApplicationTestCase.

EDIT: it's looking at the manifest of the tested project. If I move the receiver definition to the manifest of the project being tested, it's found. Is there any way to access the context / package manager of the TEST application?

Any ideas?